# How to use react-bootstrap plugins with Ruby on Rails, React and ES6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, es6-promise

I am developing a web application using Ruby on Rails, ReactJS and ES6.
I am trying to import react-bootstrap plugins (like Tokenfield for taggings) using below steps:

```
1. npm install react-bootstrap --save
2. import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
```

But i am getting error:

`ExecJS::ProgramError (TypeError: undefined is not a function).`

Could any one guide me where I am missing anything.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You might to look into HTTP://reactrb.org.